# Multiple clause query in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```html
package com.mobile.model;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "mobile_table")
public class Mobile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public int mobileId;

    @Column(name = "mobile_name",nullable = false,length = 20)
    public String mobileName;

    @Column(name = "mobile_brand",nullable = false,length = 15)
    public String mobileBrand;

    @Column(name="mobile_networkType")
    public String mobileNetworkType;

    @Column(name = "mobile_core")
    public Integer mobileAvailableCore;

    @Column(name = "mobile_ram")
    public Integer mobileRAMSize;

    @Column(name = "mobile_os")
    public String mobileOS;

    @Column(name = "mobile_wifif")
    public Boolean mobileWifiAvailability;

    @Column(name = "mobile_bluetooth")
    public Boolean mobileBluethoothAvailablity;

    public Mobile() {
    }

    public Mobile(String mobileName, String mobileBrand, String mobileNetworkType, Integer mobileAvailableCore, Integer mobileRAMSize, String mobileOS, Boolean mobileWifiAvailability, Boolean mobileBluethoothAvailablity) {
        this.mobileName = mobileName;
        this.mobileBrand = mobileBrand;
        this.mobileNetworkType = mobileNetworkType;
        this.mobileAvailableCore = mobileAvailableCore;
        this.mobileRAMSize = mobileRAMSize;
        this.mobileOS = mobileOS;
        this.mobileWifiAvailability = mobileWifiAvailability;
        this.mobileBluethoothAvailablity = mobileBluethoothAvailablity;
    }
}
```

```html
//Query for multiple selection
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List<Mobile> getMobileSearch(String mobileBrand, Integer mobileRAMSize, String mobileOS){
     return mobileDao.findAll(Specifications.where((Specification<Mobile>) getAllMobilesByBrand(mobileBrand))
       .and((Specification<Mobile>) getAllMobilesByOS(mobileOS))
       .and((Specification<Mobile>) getAllMobilesByRam(mobileRAMSize)));
    }
```

```html
// calling function for multiple attribute Search in controller class
@RequestMapping(value="/searchMobile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Mobile>> searchMobile(@RequestParam(value="brand") String mobileBrand, @RequestParam(value="ramSize") Integer ramSize, @RequestParam(value="mobileOs") String MobileOs)
    {
     List<Mobile> mobileList=mobileService.getMobileSearch(mobileBrand,ramSize,MobileOs);
     return new ResponseEntity<List<Mobile>>(mobileList,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```html
// here is how my database is calling database query.
@Repository
public interface MobileDao extends CrudRepository<Mobile, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Mobile> {

    public List<Mobile> findByMobileBrand(String mobileBrand);

    @Query("select distinct m.mobileBrand from Mobile m")
    public List<String > getAllDistinctBrand();

    public List<Mobile> findByMobileRAMSize(Integer mobileRAMSize);

    @Query("select distinct m.mobileRAMSize from Mobile m")
    public List<Integer> getAllDistinctRam();

    public List<Mobile> findByMobileOS(String mobileOS);


    @Query("select distinct m.mobileOS from Mobile m")
    public List<String > getAllDistinctMobileOS();
```

I am trying to implement the search query for products like used in different e-commerce Websites(like Flipkart, Amazon) where user inserts different attributes for the product. Based on the product Attribute, results are shown. For the implementation i am using Spring Boot and JPA as a database.

How can i search multiple clause in single query dynamically. For Example, in case of SQL query we search multiple clause like this.

How can i implement multiple clause in JPA.

```
Select * from table_name where attribute1="Attb" and attribute2="Attb2" and attribute3="Attb3";
```

Attb, Attb2 and Attb3 are dynamically changing based on client input.

Comment: That is simple "prepared statement" and spring supports that out of the box via `@Param` and `@Query`. Did you even check the Spring Data Docs ?

Comment: I have checked spring Data Docs but  I am not able to write dynamic query for different attribute. user can insert multiple attribute like ( first time user clicks only attribute1, second time attribute1 and attribute2 and so on). how to write query for these type of problems. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "JPA" is not a database. JPA uses JPQL and there are ample reference to it on the web, so kindly say what you have tried. JPQL requires CLASSES, and you present no classes

Comment: [link](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile&sid=tyy/4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=start&as-pos=1_1_ic_mobile) you can see in sidebar of website user clicks on checkbox and it shows results based on that. i have to implement similar to that.

Comment: "what you have tried" means WHAT CODE. WHAT JPQL.

Comment: @Gopal use Crietria API for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was not clear enought. If you need to use variable number of conditions, you will have to use `Criteria API`. It allows you to conditionally create list of predicates and use that for data fetch.
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

It will look like this:

```
    myQueryMethod(UserChoices choices){
        if(choices.someChoice1){
         predicates.add(somePredicate)
        }
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a JPA repository and use method queries :

```
public interface MyRepository implements JpaRepository<MODEL_CLASS, Long> {
     MODEL_CLASS findAllByAtttibute1AndAttribute2AndAttribute3(String Attribute1, String Attribute2, String Attribute3);
}
```

Comment: by using this method, i will have to write all possible combinations of Attribute. like if user want to search by only one attribute or more than one attribute then how can we write dynamic query.

Comment: @Gopal using `Criteria API`